# Generate random birthdates

Tags: sql, date, random

For testing an algorithm I would like to generate 10,000 random birthdates from 01/01/1995 to 31/12/2013. Can this be done in SQL and how?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Probably. Did you have a particular RDBMS in mind?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794637/how-to-update-rows-with-a-random-date

Comment: Use any random number generator you happen to have handy to generate numbers between 0 and 6939. Then add that number of days onto `1995-01-01`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a random date:

select cast(cast(RAND()*100000 as int) as datetime)

You can then write code around this statement to limit it to a range.

Comment: See the remark by Damien - if you use 6939 as multiplier, you don't have to add extra code to limit the range.

Comment: Well, 6940 since you want numbers >=0 and < 6940 which is what multiplying `RAND()` by 6940 will produce.