# MYSQL - how do i fill a row with random dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Well i have to update a table called "patron_filtrado" and fill one column called "fecha_nacimiento" type date. With random dates, the dates will be in a range between 1920 and 1980.

i thought on something like this

```
Update patron_filtrado
  SET fecha_nacimiento= DateAdd(d, ROUND(DateDiff(d, '1920-01-01', '2080-12-31') * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), 0),
  DATEADD(second,CHECKSUM(NEWID())%48000, '1920-01-01'))
```

im ok?

Comment: Can you specify what database and version are you using?  Oracle?  MS SQL? MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified from: [How to update rows with a random date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794637/how-to-update-rows-with-a-random-date)

NEWID is better then trying to use RAND: RAND does not generate different values row in a single SELECT or UPDATE (well it didn't in SQL 2000, in case behaviour has changed).

Try

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 22265), '1920-01-01')
FROM your_table
```

This generates dates starting from 1920-01-01 through 1980-12-31.

If you want to update, then

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_date_field = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 22265), '1920-01-01')
WHERE your_conditions
```

Comment: it say this "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(NEWID()) % 22265), '1920-01-01')' at line 1
"

Comment: Line 1 = UPDATE your_table?  Did you update it to UPDATE patron_filtrado correct?  Modify the above statement to fit into your MySQL version and syntax.

Comment: UPDATE padron_filtrado SET fecha_nacimiento = DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 22265), '1920-01-01');
i tried this