# SQL Server add new column to table and filled random integer in range

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I understand how to add a new column and default int to a table.

```
ALTER TABLE Cards
ADD Amex int NOT NULL DEFAULT(1) // how can I add a random number (between 1, to 10) or random date (jan to feb etc)?
GO
```

How do I add a **new column** into a table, and fill it with a random integer between 1 and 10, or a random date?

Edit - Answer from below:

```
Create table cards (
  Amex int NOT NULL DEFAULT (cast(right(cast(checksum(newid()) as varchar(255)), 1) as int) + 1)
);
```

Comment: For random dates, check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794637/how-to-update-rows-with-a-random-date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do an update.  For a number from 1 to 10, the following should work:

```
update cards
    set Amex = cast(right(cast(checksum(newid()) as varchar(255)), 1) as int) + 1
```

EDIT:

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d19fa) is an example of this being used in a `create table` statement.

Comment: What about random dates in a range or out of a list.

Comment: @aggie . . . You would do something similar with `checksum(newid())`, modulo arithmetic, and start and end dates.  The part of the question about dates is much vaguer than the part about integers; plus the title is about integers and not dates.

Comment: tried this  -> 'ALTER TABLE Cards
ADD Amex int NOT NULL DEFAULT(cast(right(cast(checksum(newid()) as varchar(255)), 1) as int) + 1)' _italic_//sql is giving me errors _italic_

Answer (score 1):

another way for random integer from 0 to 10 in sql-server is:

```
update cards  
set Amex = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2) % 11
```

here is a trick for a random month names:

```
= DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, (CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2) % 13), getdate()))
```