# How do I generate random date in specific range for each row in a TSQL Select?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My code is like  following
How do I generate random date in specific range for each row in a TSQL Select

```
    Declare @id int;
    Declare @randomDate;
    Declare crs Cursor For
    Select id from myTable 
    open crs 
    fetch next from crs into @id
    while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    begin
    SET @randomDate=''
    --Generate randomdate @randomDate
    update myTable set dateModified=@randomDate where id=@id;
    fetch next from crs into @id
    end
    close crs
    deallocate crs
```

Comment: You don't need a cursor, they are very slow, if you can't update the entire table in one go due to logging issues then use a while loop to update in batches. Avoid one row at a time updates.

Answer (score 1):

As per following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794637/how-to-update-rows-with-a-random-date),

```
Update myTable
SET
 dateModified = DATEADD(day, (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 65530), 0)
```

You do not need any cursors to accomplish this. [Cursors are bad](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/03/18/increase-your-sql-server-performance-by-replacing-cursors-with-set-operations/) for simple operations like this one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need specific range like between 2011/01/01 and 2016/12/12

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE to generate valid dates and select one of them randomly:

```
declare @fromDate date = cast('2016/12/12' as date),
        @toDate date = cast('2017/01/10' as date);

with cte([date]) as (
    select @fromDate
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, [date])
    from cte
    where [date] < @toDate
)
select top(1) *
from cte
order by newid();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will provide a random date between a specific start and end date.
I've introduced the @gap variable for performance reasons, it removes the cost of the DATEDIFF function out of the main query.

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '20170101'
DECLARE @end DATETIME = '20170201'
DECLARE @gap INT = DATEDIFF(DD,@start,@end)

UPDATE mytable SET dateModified = DATEADD(DD,@gap*RAND(),@start)
```