# Generate a column of random dates in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

How would I go about creating a new column of randomly selected dates with bigquery? This is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694040/how-to-generate-date-series-to-occupy-absent-dates-in-google-biqquery), but the dates should be random and not joined by anything. Ideally, it would just be a column of IDs and a column of random dates in a given range:

```
ID    Date
1     2010-01-01
2     2012-03-31
3     2011-07-11
4     2015-06-09
```

This is [easier on regular sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794637/how-to-update-rows-with-a-random-date), but I cannot get this approach to work with the bigquery sql syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH parameters AS (
  SELECT 100 ids_count, DATE '2010-01-01' start_date, DATE '2020-12-31' finish_date
)
SELECT id, DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(CAST(start + (finish - start) * RAND() AS INT64)) random_date
FROM parameters, 
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, ids_count)) id,
UNNEST([STRUCT(UNIX_DATE(start_date) AS start, UNIX_DATE(finish_date) AS finish)])
-- ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

On BigQuery by using the `RAND` function on a delimited time window:

```
-- Parameters
DECLARE start_dt DEFAULT DATE '2010-01-01'; -- Lower limit
DECLARE end_dt DEFAULT date '2020-12-31'; -- Upper limit
DECLARE n DEFAULT 30; -- Quantity of random dates

-- Random dates
SELECT DATE_ADD(start_dt , INTERVAL CAST(DATE_DIFF(end_dt, start_dt, DAY)*RAND() AS INT64) DAY) random_date
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, n));
```